# Why won't APEX authorization scheme hold stored username?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an authorization scheme for my application that checks first if the username entered is a username in the system and then whether the user has access to this particular application. The login issue I am having is that the user will login in once and get denied and have to login a second time and it works. I think the issue is that the :APP_USERNAME is not stored for the first login attempt and then is stored in the application for the second try. I know there has to be a way around this, but I have yet to figure it out.

````
    u_id number := null;
    app_id number := null;
    auth_id number := null;
    authorized number(1,0) := 0;
    auth_status char := 'f';
    failure_reason varchar2(200) := null;
begin
    begin
        select id into u_id from user where username=:APP_USERNAME;
    exception
        when NO_DATA_FOUND then
            u_id := null;
            failure_reason := 'User not found:' || :APP_USERNAME;
    end;
 
    select id into app_id from lkup_application where name='Application Name';
   
    if (u_id is not null) then
        begin
            select id into auth_id from authorization where application_id = app_id and user_id = u_id;
            exception
                when NO_DATA_FOUND then
                    auth_id := null;
                    failure_reason := 'User not authorized from authorization table.';
        end;
    end if;
   
    if (auth_id is not null) then
        authorized := 1;
        auth_status := 's';
    end if;
    
    insert into access_audit values(null, :APP_USER, app_id, current_timestamp, auth_status, failure_reason);
    commit;
 
    return (authorized = 1);
end;```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is `:APP_USER`, not `:APP_USERNAME` so I suggest you use it.